# H independent or independently sorted?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbial-phrases

I read these two sentences:

> Such an array is said to be h-sorted. Put another way, an h-sorted
>   array is h independent sorted sub-sequences, interleaved together.

I don't know the grammar behind "h-sorted" and "h independent sorted". And why is it not "h independently" sorted? For the source please refer to [this link](https://books.google.com/books?id=idUdqdDXqnAC&pg=PA258&lpg=PA258&dq=Such+an+array+is+said+to+be+h-sorted.+Put+another+way,+an+h-sorted+array+is+h+independent+sorted+sub-sequences,+interleaved+together.&source=bl&ots=Z_w10bflhS&sig=5DnxVsUPQLYJl3OxA6JC-pLoq7A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJ9-X4vfXcAhW5ITQIHVHBC3oQ6AEwAHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=Such%20an%20array%20is%20said%20to%20be%20h-sorted.%20Put%20another%20way%2C%20an%20h-sorted%20array%20is%20h%20independent%20sorted%20sub-sequences%2C%20interleaved%20together.&f=false).

Answer (score 1):

The writer is saying that an *h* sorted array can be defined as a set of *h* independently sorted subsequences, combined (interleaved).

As written you would just interpret this as some number *h* of *independent* (of each other), sorted subsequences.  However I agree the adverb *independently* seems more appropriate than the adjective *independent* in this context, and it's also unclear why he uses the variable *h* rather than the more typical variable *n* ... but perhaps these are just typical jargon in this academic field, or when writing about this subject.

Comment: *h* independent, sorted subsequences is also valid, though maybe with a slightly different meaning.